# Dealing with under flow while calculating GMM parameters using EM

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing

I am currently runnuing training  in matlab on a matrix of logspecrum samples  I am constantly dealing with underflow problems.I understood that I need to work with log's in order to deal with underflowing.
I am still strugling with uderflow though , when i calculate the mean (mue) bucause it is negetive i cant work with logs so i need the real values that underflow. 
These are equasions i am working with:
[image]

In MATLAB code i calulate log_tau in oreder avoid underflow but when calulating  mue i need exp(log(tau)) which goes to zero.
I am attaching relevent MATLAB code 
**in the code i called the variable alpha is tau ...

```
for i = 1 : 50
        log_c = Logsum(log_alpha,1) - log(N);
        c = exp(log_c);
        mue = DataMat*alpha./(repmat(exp(Logsum(log_alpha,1)),FrameSize,1));
        log_abs_mue = log(abs(mue));
        log_SigmaSqr = log((DataMat.^2)*alpha) - repmat(Logsum(log_alpha,1),FrameSize,1) - 2*log_abs_mue;
        SigmaSqr = exp(log_SigmaSqr);
        for j=1:N
            rep_DataMat(:,:,j) = repmat(DataMat(:,j),1,M);
            log_gamma(j,:) = log_c - 0.5*(FrameSize*log(2*pi)+sum(log_SigmaSqr)) + sum((rep_DataMat(:,:,j) - mue).^2./(2*SigmaSqr));
        end
        log_alpha = log_gamma - repmat(Logsum(log_gamma,2),1,M);
        alpha = exp(log_alpha);
    end        
    c = exp(log_c);
    SigmaSqr = exp(log_SigmaSqr);
```

does any one see how i can avoid this? or what needs to be fixed in code?

Answer (score 0):

What i did was add this line to the MATLAB code:

```
mue(isnan(mue))=0; %fix 0/0 problem
```

and this one:

```
SigmaSqr(SigmaSqr==0)=1;%fix if mue_k = x_k
```

not sure if this is the best solution but is seems to work...
any have a better idea?